# How to pass session/cookie in function loginpage_hook() in moodle/lib/authlib.php

Tags: php, moodle

```
function loginpage_hook() 
{
    global $frm;  // can be used to override submitted login form
    global $user; // can be used to replace authenticate_user_login()
    $_POST["username"] = $_SESSION['user_login_id'];
    $_POST["password"] = $_SESSION['password'];
}
```

so abov function `loginpage_hook()` in `moodle/lib/authlib.php` for use SSO

I need to help how to use session/cookie in this function but session/cookie it is create by my another PHP application

I can try to create session/cookie my PHP application with path  but it is not available in this function/file

please help me to solution